# Cordova fixed element disappearing on scroll

Tags: html, css, cordova, css-position, fixed

I noticed a bug in Cordova where a fixed element on scroll disappears when scrolling through the page (usually when I scroll fast)

Any idea on why this is happening?

I have made a gif of the issue here [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/slxpiHv.gifv)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}

.elementFixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: code please....

Comment: html, body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
.elementFixed{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: please show some working example, try to replicate the problem, so people can play around your problem and come up with possible solution. Add HTML as well.